# Set web app in azure through github, but failed to deploy

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service

I upload my code to GitHub and it showed me deploy successful, but when I set the web app in Azure and it showed me an application error. How can I set the web application in azure?[this is my code](https://github.com/Zhoucheny/markets_sqn1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set the web application in azure?

- I have followed the below steps and able to deploy the Application to Azure
- Create your application using VSCode
- In Azure Portal create Python App Service
- Create a new repository in GitHub
- In VSCode, Source Control => Pull , Push => Push to = >Add a New Remote = > Add a remote from GitHub ( Select your created empty Repository)
- Navigate to ***Azure App service***, => ***Deployment Center*** =>***Settings*** => ***GitHub*** => Enter ***Organization*** and ***Repository details*** => ***Save***

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Now access your URL

[image]